# cakephp : how to displays the checkbox value that has been selected in from edit

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

```
echo $this->Form->input('product_id', array(
                                                'label'=>false,
                                                'type'=>'select',
                                                'multiple'=>'checkbox',
                                                'options'=>$product,


                                            ));
```

I am trying to adding 'checked=>true' in from input but failed

[image: this is screenshoot of the form edit, the data already selected is not checked]

this is screenshoot of the form edit, the data already selected is not checked

Answer (score 0):

You can tell CakePHP which checkboxes are checked by passing an array of `selected` values:-

```
$selected = []; // An array of selected values
echo $this->Form->input('product_id', array(
    'label' => false,
    'type' => 'select',
    'multiple' => 'checkbox',
    'options' => $product,
    'selected' => $selected
));
```

If you wanted to select all the values to start with you could pass the array keys of `$product` to the `selected` option:-

```
$selected = array_keys($product);
echo $this->Form->input('product_id', array(
    'label' => false,
    'type' => 'select',
    'multiple' => 'checkbox',
    'options' => $product,
    'selected' => $selected
));
```

Comment: If the displayed data that has been selected or already saved, then how ?, because the form add has been selected, then the problem now is on the form edit